# PHPMyAdmin syntax error

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I am using phpMyAdmin and have created the parent table, by inserting the sql code, but when inserting the query using the same data without the table headers I am getting a syntax error:........

SQL query:

```
INSERT INTO `manufacturers` (`manufacturerid`, `name`) VALUES  (1001, ‘Aladdin Lighting');
INSERT INTO `manufacturers` (`manufacturerid`, `name`) VALUES  (1002, ‘Alumilite Lighting');
```

MySQL said: Documentation

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Lighting');
>   INSERT INTO `manufacturers` (`manufacturerid`, `name`) VALUES  (100' at line 1

Here is the SQL:

```
INSERT INTO `manufacturers` (`manufacturerid`, `name`) VALUES  (1001, ‘Aladdin Lighting');
INSERT INTO `manufacturers` (`manufacturerid`, `name`) VALUES  (1002, ‘Alumilite Lighting');
INSERT INTO `manufacturers` (`manufacturerid`, `name`) VALUES  (1003, ‘Ametrix Lighting');
INSERT INTO `manufacturers` (`manufacturerid`, `name`) VALUES  (1004, ‘Arancia Lighting');
INSERT INTO `manufacturers` (`manufacturerid`, `name`) VALUES  (1005, ‘Atlantic Lighting');
INSERT INTO `manufacturers` (`manufacturerid`, `name`) VALUES  (1006, ‘Atomis Lighting');
INSERT INTO `manufacturers` (`manufacturerid`, `name`) VALUES  (1007, ‘Axis Lighting');
INSERT INTO `manufacturers` (`manufacturerid`, `name`) VALUES  (1008, ‘Bock Lighting');
INSERT INTO `manufacturers` (`manufacturerid`, `name`) VALUES  (1009, ‘Brightlines');
INSERT INTO `manufacturers` (`manufacturerid`, `name`) VALUES  (1010, ‘C-3 Lighting Solutions');
INSERT INTO `manufacturers` (`manufacturerid`, `name`) VALUES  (1011, ‘Carmanah');
INSERT INTO `manufacturers` (`manufacturerid`, `name`) VALUES  (1012, ‘Cast Lighting');
INSERT INTO `manufacturers` (`manufacturerid`, `name`) VALUES  (1013, ‘Castaldi');
INSERT INTO `manufacturers` (`manufacturerid`, `name`) VALUES  (1014, ‘CD Lighting');
INSERT INTO `manufacturers` (`manufacturerid`, `name`) VALUES  (1015, ‘Corelite');
INSERT INTO `manufacturers` (`manufacturerid`, `name`) VALUES  (1016, ‘Dark');
INSERT INTO `manufacturers` (`manufacturerid`, `name`) VALUES  (1017, ‘DLS Lighting');
INSERT INTO `manufacturers` (`manufacturerid`, `name`) VALUES  (1018, ‘Eclipse Lighting');
INSERT INTO `manufacturers` (`manufacturerid`, `name`) VALUES  (1019, ‘Edge Lighting ');
INSERT INTO `manufacturers` (`manufacturerid`, `name`) VALUES  (1020, ‘Egoluce');
INSERT INTO `manufacturers` (`manufacturerid`, `name`) VALUES  (1021, ‘Element');
INSERT INTO `manufacturers` (`manufacturerid`, `name`) VALUES  (1022, ‘Eureka Lighting');
INSERT INTO `manufacturers` (`manufacturerid`, `name`) VALUES  (1023, ‘Evenlite, Inc.');
INSERT INTO `manufacturers` (`manufacturerid`, `name`) VALUES  (1024, ‘Evergreen Lighting');
INSERT INTO `manufacturers` (`manufacturerid`, `name`) VALUES  (1025, ‘Fail-Safe Lighting');
INSERT INTO `manufacturers` (`manufacturerid`, `name`) VALUES  (1026, ‘Functional Devices');
INSERT INTO `manufacturers` (`manufacturerid`, `name`) VALUES  (1027, ‘Greengate Controls');
INSERT INTO `manufacturers` (`manufacturerid`, `name`) VALUES  (1028, ‘Halo Commercial ');
INSERT INTO `manufacturers` (`manufacturerid`, `name`) VALUES  (1029, ‘Halo Lighting');
INSERT INTO `manufacturers` (`manufacturerid`, `name`) VALUES  (1030, ‘Ilfari');
INSERT INTO `manufacturers` (`manufacturerid`, `name`) VALUES  (1031, ‘Illumitex');
INSERT INTO `manufacturers` (`manufacturerid`, `name`) VALUES  (1032, ‘iLumin');
INSERT INTO `manufacturers` (`manufacturerid`, `name`) VALUES  (1033, ‘Impact Lighting');
INSERT INTO `manufacturers` (`manufacturerid`, `name`) VALUES  (1034, ‘Incon Lighting');
INSERT INTO `manufacturers` (`manufacturerid`, `name`) VALUES  (1035, ‘Invue Lighting');
INSERT INTO `manufacturers` (`manufacturerid`, `name`) VALUES  (1036, ‘iO Lighting');
INSERT INTO `manufacturers` (`manufacturerid`, `name`) VALUES  (1037, ‘Iota Engineering');
INSERT INTO `manufacturers` (`manufacturerid`, `name`) VALUES  (1038, ‘IRiS Lighting');
INSERT INTO `manufacturers` (`manufacturerid`, `name`) VALUES  (1039, ‘ISI Inverter Systems');
INSERT INTO `manufacturers` (`manufacturerid`, `name`) VALUES  (1040, ‘Ivalo Lighting');
INSERT INTO `manufacturers` (`manufacturerid`, `name`) VALUES  (1041, ‘J & J Electronics');
INSERT INTO `manufacturers` (`manufacturerid`, `name`) VALUES  (1042, ‘Jefferson Lighting');
INSERT INTO `manufacturers` (`manufacturerid`, `name`) VALUES  (1043, ‘JLC Tech');
INSERT INTO `manufacturers` (`manufacturerid`, `name`) VALUES  (1044, ‘King Lighting');
INSERT INTO `manufacturers` (`manufacturerid`, `name`) VALUES  (1045, ‘Kurtzon Lighting');
INSERT INTO `manufacturers` (`manufacturerid`, `name`) VALUES  (1046, ‘KW Industries');
INSERT INTO `manufacturers` (`manufacturerid`, `name`) VALUES  (1047, ‘Lightology');
INSERT INTO `manufacturers` (`manufacturerid`, `name`) VALUES  (1048, ‘Liteworx');
INSERT INTO `manufacturers` (`manufacturerid`, `name`) VALUES  (1049, ‘Louvers International');
INSERT INTO `manufacturers` (`manufacturerid`, `name`) VALUES  (1050, ‘Lumark Lighting');
INSERT INTO `manufacturers` (`manufacturerid`, `name`) VALUES  (1051, ‘Lumascape');
INSERT INTO `manufacturers` (`manufacturerid`, `name`) VALUES  (1052, ‘Lumenpulse');
INSERT INTO `manufacturers` (`manufacturerid`, `name`) VALUES  (1053, ‘Lumiere Lighting');
INSERT INTO `manufacturers` (`manufacturerid`, `name`) VALUES  (1054, ‘Lumux Architectural Lighting');
INSERT INTO `manufacturers` (`manufacturerid`, `name`) VALUES  (1055, ‘Luraline Lighting');
INSERT INTO `manufacturers` (`manufacturerid`, `name`) VALUES  (1056, ‘Lutron Electronics');
INSERT INTO `manufacturers` (`manufacturerid`, `name`) VALUES  (1057, ‘Lutron Shading Solutions ');
INSERT INTO `manufacturers` (`manufacturerid`, `name`) VALUES  (1058, ‘Main Street Lighting');
INSERT INTO `manufacturers` (`manufacturerid`, `name`) VALUES  (1059, ‘Matthew\'s Fan Company');
INSERT INTO `manufacturers` (`manufacturerid`, `name`) VALUES  (1060, ‘McFadden Lighting');
INSERT INTO `manufacturers` (`manufacturerid`, `name`) VALUES  (1061, ‘McGraw-Edison Lighting');
INSERT INTO `manufacturers` (`manufacturerid`, `name`) VALUES  (1062, ‘Metalux Lighting');
INSERT INTO `manufacturers` (`manufacturerid`, `name`) VALUES  (1063, ‘MWS Lighting');
INSERT INTO `manufacturers` (`manufacturerid`, `name`) VALUES  (1064, ‘Nafco International');
INSERT INTO `manufacturers` (`manufacturerid`, `name`) VALUES  (1065, ‘Neoray Lighting');
INSERT INTO `manufacturers` (`manufacturerid`, `name`) VALUES  (1066, ‘Nexxus Lighting');
INSERT INTO `manufacturers` (`manufacturerid`, `name`) VALUES  (1067, ‘Phoenix Products');
INSERT INTO `manufacturers` (`manufacturerid`, `name`) VALUES  (1068, ‘Picasso Lighting');
INSERT INTO `manufacturers` (`manufacturerid`, `name`) VALUES  (1069, ‘Portfolio Lighting');
INSERT INTO `manufacturers` (`manufacturerid`, `name`) VALUES  (1070, ‘Pure Lighting');
INSERT INTO `manufacturers` (`manufacturerid`, `name`) VALUES  (1071, ‘RSA Lighting');
INSERT INTO `manufacturers` (`manufacturerid`, `name`) VALUES  (1072, ‘Sentry Lighting');
INSERT INTO `manufacturers` (`manufacturerid`, `name`) VALUES  (1073, ‘Shaper Lighting');
INSERT INTO `manufacturers` (`manufacturerid`, `name`) VALUES  (1074, ‘Sillites');
INSERT INTO `manufacturers` (`manufacturerid`, `name`) VALUES  (1075, ‘SMC LED');
INSERT INTO `manufacturers` (`manufacturerid`, `name`) VALUES  (1076, ‘Sports Sentry Systems');
INSERT INTO `manufacturers` (`manufacturerid`, `name`) VALUES  (1077, ‘SQ1 Precision Lighting');
INSERT INTO `manufacturers` (`manufacturerid`, `name`) VALUES  (1078, ‘Stagecraft Industries');
INSERT INTO `manufacturers` (`manufacturerid`, `name`) VALUES  (1079, ‘Starfire Lighting');
INSERT INTO `manufacturers` (`manufacturerid`, `name`) VALUES  (1080, ‘Street Lighting Equipment');
INSERT INTO `manufacturers` (`manufacturerid`, `name`) VALUES  (1081, ‘Stresscrete');
INSERT INTO `manufacturers` (`manufacturerid`, `name`) VALUES  (1082, ‘Structura ');
INSERT INTO `manufacturers` (`manufacturerid`, `name`) VALUES  (1083, ‘Sure-Lites Lighting ');
INSERT INTO `manufacturers` (`manufacturerid`, `name`) VALUES  (1084, ‘Tech Lighting ');
INSERT INTO `manufacturers` (`manufacturerid`, `name`) VALUES  (1085, ‘Technilite ');
INSERT INTO `manufacturers` (`manufacturerid`, `name`) VALUES  (1086, ‘The Light Edge ');
INSERT INTO `manufacturers` (`manufacturerid`, `name`) VALUES  (1087, ‘Tiella Lighting ');
INSERT INTO `manufacturers` (`manufacturerid`, `name`) VALUES  (1088, ‘Tokistar Lighting ');
INSERT INTO `manufacturers` (`manufacturerid`, `name`) VALUES  (1089, ‘USL Lighting ');
INSERT INTO `manufacturers` (`manufacturerid`, `name`) VALUES  (1090, ‘Venture Lighting ');
INSERT INTO `manufacturers` (`manufacturerid`, `name`) VALUES  (1091, ‘Verbatim Lighting');
INSERT INTO `manufacturers` (`manufacturerid`, `name`) VALUES  (1092, ‘Viso Lighting');
INSERT INTO `manufacturers` (`manufacturerid`, `name`) VALUES  (1093, ‘Vista Pro');
INSERT INTO `manufacturers` (`manufacturerid`, `name`) VALUES  (1094, ‘Vistosi');
INSERT INTO `manufacturers` (`manufacturerid`, `name`) VALUES  (1095, ‘Visual Lighting');
INSERT INTO `manufacturers` (`manufacturerid`, `name`) VALUES  (1096, ‘Voigt Lighting');
INSERT INTO `manufacturers` (`manufacturerid`, `name`) VALUES  (1097, ‘Wilmette Lighting');
INSERT INTO `manufacturers` (`manufacturerid`, `name`) VALUES  (1098, ‘WPT Design ');
INSERT INTO `manufacturers` (`manufacturerid`, `name`) VALUES  (1099, ‘XAL Lighting ');
INSERT INTO `manufacturers` (`manufacturerid`, `name`) VALUES  (1100, ‘Zaneen Lighting');
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the opening single quote is a smart quote and the ending single quote is just a tick. Make sure that `‘` is `'` instead.

```
INSERT INTO manufacturers (manufacturerid, name) VALUES (1100, ‘Zaneen Lighting');
```

should be

```
 INSERT INTO manufacturers (manufacturerid, name) VALUES (1100, 'Zaneen Lighting');
```